# Adding title and space between tables subplots

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

My script generates three tables using matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.  The attached image shows that the first table is partially visible on top and other tables overlap. I have also attached a working code snippet. I need to add a title on top of each table and create some space on top of each table. How can I accomplish that? Any help appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import argparse
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

def _draw_table1( axis):
    colLabels = ('', '')
    rowLabels = ('Start Date - End Date',
                 'Total Return since inception',
                 'Average Annual ROR',
                 'Winning / Losing Months',
                 'Winning Month Gain / Losing Month Loss',
                 'Sharpe Ratio',
                 'Risk of Ruin',
                 'Return to Drawdown (Calmar)',
                 '% Winning / Losing Days [Flat Days]')
    data = [['2015-01-01 - 2018-04-27'], ['12.50 %'], [' 3.09 %'], [' 1.35'], [' 2.01 / -1.99 %'], [' 0.34'], [' 0.96'], [' 0.25'], ['50.05 / 49.95 [ 0.00 ]']]
    axis.axis('off')
    axis.axis('tight')
    axis.get_frame_on()

    colorscell = [["#D0DDAF"],[ "#E6E9E9"],[ "#D0DDAF"],[ "#E6E9E9"],[ "#D0DDAF"],[ "#E6E9E9"],[ "#D0DDAF"],[ "#E6E9E9"],[ "#D0DDAF"]]
    colorsrow = ["#D0DDAF", "#E6E9E9", "#D0DDAF", "#E6E9E9", "#D0DDAF", "#E6E9E9", "#D0DDAF", "#E6E9E9", "#D0DDAF"]
    the_table = axis.table(cellText=data,
                             rowLabels=rowLabels,
                             colLabels=None,
                             loc='center right',
                             cellColours=colorscell,
                             rowColours=colorsrow,
                             bbox=[0.3, -0.2, 0.5, 1.5])

    table_props = the_table.properties()

def _draw_year_analysis( axis):
    rowLabels = ('Annual return',
                 'Best 21 days',
                 'Worst 21 days',
                 '1 year sharpe')

    data = [['-5.20 %', '15.83 %', ' 4.10 %' ,'-0.87 %'],
           [' 4.79 %', ' 9.12 %', ' 4.25 %', ' 1.70 %'], ['-4.89 %', '-6.87 %' ,'-4.80 %' ,'-2.01 %'], 
           [-0.49, 1.09, 0.45, -0.4]]

    colLabels = [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]
    colorscell = [["#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9", "#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9"],[ "#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9", "#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9"],[ "#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9", "#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9"],[ "#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9", "#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9"]]
    colorsrow = ["#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9", "#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9"]
    colorscolumn = ["#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9", "#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9"]
    axis.axis('off')

    the_table = axis.table(cellText=data,
                           rowLabels=rowLabels,
                           colLabels= colLabels,
                           cellColours= colorscell,
                           colColours= colorscolumn,
                           rowColours = colorsrow,
                           loc='left',
                           bbox=[0.0, -0.1, 1.0, 1.5])
    table_props = the_table.properties()
    table_cells = table_props['children']

def _draw_drawdowns_table(axis):

    data = [['-13.06 %', datetime.date(2015, 1, 7), datetime.date(2016, 2, 22), 351.0],
            ['-8.80 %', datetime.date(2016, 10, 13), datetime.date(2017, 8, 6), 254.0],
            ['-7.27 %', datetime.date(2017, 8, 30), datetime.date(2018, 4, 27), 205.0],
            ['-6.60 %', datetime.date(2016, 4, 8), datetime.date(2016, 6, 22), 65.0],
            ['-3.67 %', datetime.date(2016, 7, 6), datetime.date(2016, 8, 9), 30.0],
            ['-3.60 %' ,datetime.date(2016, 8, 16), datetime.date(2016, 9, 30), 40.0]]

    colLabels = ('Depth', 'Start', 'End', 'Length (days)')
    axis.axis('off')
    axis.axis('tight')

    colorscell=[]
    for i in range(len(data)):
        tmpList= []
        for x in range(4):
            tmpList.append("#D0DDAF")
        colorscell.append(tmpList)

    colorsrow = ["#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9", "#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9", "#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9"]
    colorscolumn = ["#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9", "#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9"]
    the_table = axis.table(cellText=data,
                           colLabels=colLabels,
                           cellColours = colorscell,
                           loc='right',
                           bbox=[0.52, -0.2, 0.5, 1.5])


def _draw_day_analysis_table( axis):
    days = [1, 5, 21, 63, 126, 252]
    rowLabels = list(map(lambda x: str(x)+" days", days))
    colLabels = ['Best', 'Worst', 'Avg', 'Curr']

    data = [[' 6.38 %', '-2.65 %', ' 0.01 %', ' 1.22 %'], [' 8.36 %', '-4.25 %', ' 0.06 %',
            ' 0.53 %'], [' 9.12 %', '-6.87 %', ' 0.25 %', ' 0.97 %'], ['13.28 %', '-8.23 %'
            , ' 1.05 %', '-1.19 %'], ['17.53 %', '-8.50 %', ' 2.53 %', '-0.08 %'], 
            ['24.12 %', '-8.68 %', ' 6.58 %', ' 0.43 %']]

    axis.axis('off')
    axis.axis('tight')

    colorscell = [["#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9", "#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9"],["#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9", "#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9"],["#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9", "#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9"],["#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9", "#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9"],["#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9", "#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9"],["#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9", "#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9"]]
    colorsrow = ["#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9", "#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9", "#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9"]
    colorscolumn = ["#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9", "#D0DDAF","#E6E9E9"]

    the_table = axis.table(cellText=data,
                           rowLabels=rowLabels,
                           colLabels=colLabels,
                           cellColours = colorscell,
                           rowColours = colorsrow,
                           colColours = colorscolumn,
                           loc='center',
                           bbox=[0.0, -0.2, 0.5, 1.5])


def plot_returns():
    f, axarr = plt.subplots(3)
    print(type(axarr) )
    print((axarr[0]) )
    _draw_table1( axarr[0])
    _draw_year_analysis( axarr[1])
    _draw_day_analysis_table( axarr[2])
    _draw_drawdowns_table(axarr[2])

    #f.suptitle('test title', fontsize=20)
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, bottom=0.1,top=1.5)
    f.tight_layout()
    plt.show()


def main():

    plot_returns()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: First thing to try would probably be to use more height spacing, `plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.3)` or so and to delete the line `tight_layout` (because that invalidates all previously set parameters).

Comment: Thanks  ImportanceOfBeingErnest. I was able to generate space between the tables using the changes you suggested. Still have one issue - I am setting the table title using axis.set_title('Title1') which works fine for the first two subplots but need to generate separate titles for the two tables in last subplot.  Will greatly appreciate any suggestions regarding setting the titles. Thanks.